# what does argument scale do actually because after running the code below the three columns (4:6) changed to decimals

Tags: r, scale

```
hab <- read.csv('cov.csv') 
names(hab[4:6])   
hab1 <- as.data.frame(scale(hab[4:6]))
```

For eg.

```
x <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
x

1    6
2    7
3    8
4    9
5   10
```

I applied scale argument to this matrix

```
scale(x)
#This gets changed to        
-1.2649111 -1.2649111
-0.6324555 -0.6324555
 0.0000000  0.0000000
 0.6324555  0.6324555
 1.2649111  1.2649111
```

Comment: Have you looked at the help file? `?scale`

Answer (score 0):

It's simply doing the following in one step for both columns of the your matrix:

```
(x[,1]-mean(x[,1]))/sd(x[,1])
```

So, in words: the mean of a column vector is subtracted from every element of the a column vector resulting in a another vector. Then every element of the this new vector is divided by the standard deviation (that's a scalar) of the initial column vector. This is done for both columns. You may have encountered this in a statistics textbook as:

![foo+bar](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=(x-\mu%20)%2F\sigma)

`Scale` can do a bit more than that, but in your example it does exactly that. As suggested in the comments, check `?scale`, particularly the examples.